# Insert id into another table and give the item another id that is autocrementing?

Tags: sql-server

Need this answered if anyone can help. I need to create a query that will automatically insert ordID, but give it a new auto incremented OrderNumber in Orders.dbo. Fiddle is below:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1492f/1/0

Comment: Did you just mean to make that column [an `IDENTITY` column](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx)?

Comment: I want to do the insert but when ordID comes in with its id, I want it to automatically get an OrderNumber. I can't use the where ordID = 521. I just want the ordID that is inserted to get its own OrderNumber in the the new table. There may be 521 already existing. So It will have to take the next number after the highest OrderNumber that already exists. Hope that clarifies.

Comment: If I use the seed / increment method, I would have to enter seed number everytime. This will eventually be a trigger that when a new order comes into orders.dbo, it will automatically be inserted into Orders.dbo and assigned an order number.

Comment: No, you would enter the seed/increment *once*, when you create the table. SQL Server automatically increments for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make ordID an identity column, and when you do the insert explicitly list the fields except ordID. SQL will auto-increment the value in the column. You can seed the column with whatever number you like, e.g. start with 522.

Comment: An example possibly?

Comment: CREATE TABLE MyCustomers (ordID int IDENTITY (100,1), otherfield nvarchar (50))    

insert MyCustomers (otherfield) values ('firstrecord') 

When you do the insert SQL will populate the ordID field.

Comment: Given the table exists can I use:  UPDATE TABLE MyCustomers (ordID int IDENTITY (100,1), otherfield nvarchar (50)) insert MyCustomers (otherfield) values ('firstrecord') When you do the insert SQL will populate the ordID field

Comment: No. Check this out: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049210/adding-an-identity-to-an-existing-column